# Can't download Android Plugin component: android-plugin-resources: Check logs for details

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

I used to develop android apps using Intellij in the past but ever since i got my new laptop i am completely unable to make any android apps.
At first i had issues with the java version i had installed (17, android seems to be incompatible?) where i was unable to even build or import a project, which i solved by only installing java version 11 (which currently still is the only installed version).
I can build and import projects just fine but whenever i try to launch it on my S8+ running android 9 (same thing when i use android 10 or higher using and avd), it gives me the following error: `Can't download Android Plugin component: android-plugin-resources: Check logs for details` and it refuses to install on my phone.

I have removed and installed a different android sdk multiple times on my pc (currently i have api 31 installed), but the issue persists. Same thing for projects i worke on in the past, i only imported the project that used to work completely fine in the past, and the error appears.

Answer (score 0):

export logs detail, it indicate this

```
 WARN - oad.AndroidComponentDownloader - Can't download Android Plugin component: android-plugin-resources 
java.io.IOException: Failed to download 'https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/intellij-dependencies/org/jetbrains/intellij/deps/android/tools/base/android-plugin-resources/27.3.0.0/android-plugin-resources-27.3.0.0.zip':
Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
```

so download this zip file and import it in your ide